# Something like Windows 10 cortana but for Ubuntu 18.04 and/or 20.04?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, microsoft

Was looking for something like Cortana from Microsoft Windows 10 but for Ubuntu 18.04 and/or 20.04?

(Currently running a triple boot with Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu cinnamon remix 20.04, and Windows 10)

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but heard good stuff about it, especiially privacy-wise: Open Assistant https://www.openassistant.org/